# Akka deathwatch - watching for Terminations and Restarts

Tags: akka

I have two actors, parent and child. The parent watches the child using content.watch(child). If the child calls context.stop(self) the parent receives a Terminated message. However if the child throws an exception akka restarts it but it does not sent a Terminated message to the parent.

```
class Parent ... {
  def receive = {
    case "start" =>
      val child = ...
      context.watch(child)
      child ! "throw"
    case Terminated(actor) => logger.error(s"$actor died"")
  }
}

class Child ... {
  def receive = {
    case "stop" => context.stop(self) // parent is notified
    case "throw" => throw new Exception("oops") // parent is not notified
  }
}
```

How can the parent actor monitor the child and watch for any terminations/restarts?

One option I came up with is to override the supervisor strategy in the parent to stop on any exceptions:

```
class Parent ... {
  override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
    case _: Exception => Stop
  }
}
```

As I understand it this will apply to ALL children of this actor. Ideally I would like to have a different supervisor strategy for individual children (types of actors) so I thought to use

```
class Child ... {
  override def postRestart(reason: Throwable): Unit = context.stop(self) 
}
```

I works but it seems like a bit of a hack. Are there any other options that I'm not aware of?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any per actor type supervision model, but what comes to mind is that you could catch the exception in the child actor and wrap it into an envelope:

```
try {
  ...
} catch {
  case e: Throwable => throw new DontRestartMeException(e)
}
```

Or even easier if you throw an exception manually, just throw the wrapped one directly.

And then in the parent decide per exception type:

```
override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
    case e: DontRestartMeException => Stop
    case _: Exception => Restart
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this idea

Answer (score 0):

The Akka actor supervision strategy is more focused on handling exceptions and based on exceptions you can decide the actions to follow.

In your case, you want to make it actor based and if that's the case different types of actors must be returning different exceptions.

So, it's better to take action based on the exception type instead. If that's not the case and similar exceptions being thrown then it's better to wrap them on actor level and then throwback to the higher-level actor.